# docker postgresql: How come the public schema owner is not postgres of the new database created if i specify POSTGRES_USER="testing"

Tags: postgresql, docker, schema

I have the following configuration in the docker-compose file

```
  postgresql:
    image: "postgres:11-alpine"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./postgresql
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'testing'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'testing'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'testing'
      PGDATA: '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata'
```

When i run docker-compose i found that there is a role called `testing` and a database called `testing`

The database `testing` has a `schema` called `public`.

I see the `owner` of the `public` is `testing`

How is this possible. Generally when we create a new database the `template1` is copied. So the owner of the schema `public` should be `postgres`

If it is set by the Dockerfile then how it is done. I want to know which command does this.

I checked the `docker-entrypoint.sh` https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/33bccfcaddd0679f55ee1028c012d26cd196537d/11/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh

I found one command used to create the user.
the command is

```
eval 'initdb --username="$POSTGRES_USER" --pwfile=<(echo "$POSTGRES_PASSWORD") '"$POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS"' "$@"'
```

How can we use `initdb` to create user. Generally we `CREATE ROLE` sql or `createuser` command

If possible how exactly this is achieving the `public` owner changed to `testing`

ALSO i found the `public` schema owner for database name `postgres` is also `testing`.

Comment: Do you know how exactly Docker creates the database? If it runs `create database testing owner testing;`  then this is to be expected.

Comment: what does `initdb --username="$POSTGRES_USER"` does in the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file. can you check my updated quesiton.

Comment: `initdb` does someting completely different. That initializes the data directory. Creating the database is the next step **after** that. But initdb allows to specify the name of the superuser and that's what that script does. So the Docker script creates a superuser named `testing` rather than a superuser named `postgres`

Comment: Yes Thats what is the reason. because i didnt find any role called `postgres`